# Regex IsMatch stops matching

Tags: c#, .net-core

I'm writing a checker with Regex, and I'm testing results with one of the popular tools:
https://regex101.com/r/DeMWEy/1

I have a list of strings that should match:

```
Process(Bystronic.Ads.GraphQL)\% Processor Time
Process(Bystronic.ParameterTuning.WebApi.Service)\\% Processor Time
Process(Bystronic.Ads.GraphQL)\\IO Write Bytes/sec
Process(DcCutting)\\IO Read Bytes/sec
Process(DcCutting)\\% Processor Time
```

And a regex that should match all of them.

```
"Process(.+)\\.+"
```

Here is a MVC:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class MainClass
{

    private static bool IsProcessMatch(string column)
    {
        return Regex.IsMatch(column, "Process(.+)\\.+");
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        var result1 = IsProcessMatch("Process(Bystronic.Ads.GraphQL)\\% Processor Time");
        var result2 = IsProcessMatch("Process(Bystronic.ParameterTuning.WebApi.Service)\\% Processor Time");
        var result3 = IsProcessMatch("Process(Bystronic.Ads.GraphQL)\\IO Write Bytes/sec");
        var result4 = IsProcessMatch("Process(DcCutting)\\IO Read Bytes/sec");
        var result5 = IsProcessMatch("Process(DcCutting)\\% Processor Time");

        Console.WriteLine(result1);
        Console.WriteLine(result2);
        Console.WriteLine(result3);
        Console.WriteLine(result4);
        Console.WriteLine(result5);
    }
}
```

I'm getting a match in the first and second one, but not in the rest. Can somebody explain me the difference between them?

Comment: @fubo That's exactly why I'm asking here. Because it matches there, but not in the code.

Comment: [This is what a mcve](https://dotnetfiddle.net/) for this should look like. ASP.NET has nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# treats the pattern a little different than the regex engine used page that you posted. On the left side there is a menu where you can choose the flavor. If you choose C# you will see:

[image]

that one little detail is missing: `@` in your code. The page will add it for you

```
private bool IsProcessColumn(string column)
{
    return Regex.IsMatch(column, @"Process(.+)\\.+");
}
```

Here is a [fiddle for testing](https://dotnetfiddle.net/PBWWb9)

Explanation: The problem is that the character `\` is a special character and in the context of regex also ambiguous.

1. It is used as escape character in a normal string.
2. In Regex it is used for special characters like `\d` (digits) and to mark the real character like: `\.` (matching a real dot)

So without the `@` the pattern is interpreted as looking for a dot because the first backslash is an escape character that makes the second backslash to a modifier for regex which is applied to the dot: `\.`. You can test it by inserting a dot into the last string:

```
string a5 = "Process(DcCutting)\\%. Processor Time";
```

and you will have a match with your original pattern.

Using the `@` (which means that you don't need to escape special characters) results in the first backslash being treated already as a modifier for regex which is then applied to the second backslash: `\\` which tries to match a real backslash in the string, and the `.` is then interpreted as a wildcart.

Sounds horribly complicated. I hope I was at least a little understandable